# Custom CSS for main full resolution higher than 1024px

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have an issue currently. I'm using a theme in wordpress and I have repositioned the header logo using custom CSS.

The problem is on the mobile version it hides my header image and moves the logo underneath the mobile menu.

Here is what I have for the current normal viewing size:

```
.header-middle .col-sm-3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.header-middle .col-sm-9 {
    width: 100%;
}
.header-middle .header-logo{
    position:absolute;
    text-align: justify;
    width:300px; /* you can use % */
    height: auto;
}
```

I would like that to not work when the mobile version kicks in for lower resolution sizes so then it views normal again.

[xeronohosting.com](http://www.xeronohosting.com) (temp link) also looks fine on normal display but the header background disappears when custom CSS is applied and viewed on a mobile version. So I'd like to keep the header background and logo in same position once on mobile then the mobile menu to be below those 2 sections as it displays before I applied the custom css

I have tried a couple of solutions and non seem to work so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We need to see the HTML and/or a complete web-page showing this. We cannot determine anything from CSS alone.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Based on present question: media queries: https://www.google.it/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=media+queries&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=sKePWIi4N6TC8gerh52YAg

Comment: xeronohosting.com (temp link) also it looks fine on normal display but the header background disappears when custom css is applied and viewed on a mobile version. so id like to keep the header background and logo in same position once on mobile then the mobile menu to be below those 2 sections as it displays before i applied the custom css

Answer (score 0):

probably (depending on the actual HTML) this will help:

```
.header-middle .header-logo{
    position:absolute;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:300px; 
    height: auto;
}
```

That keeps it at or below its parents width (100%) and limits it to not become wider than 300px.

Comment: Its basically the first part of the css disspears and the logo is displayed on its own. its a weird one the middle part handles the menu links etc.

This will have helped but it didnt resolve the problem i shall emend my post and add this.